# How to estimate signal from modified power spectrum?

Tags: signals, signal-processing

Originally, I have audio signal, perform windowing with 25ms frame and 10ms overlapping and transform it into STFT power spectrum while the phase information is kept. Then, I perform some modification on the spectrum. Now, I am trying to estimate the signal from modified STFT power spectrum.
  I have searched some papers talking about it. One method is estimating the audio signal by minimizing the difference between modified power spectrum and power spectrum of estimated signal. However, this method work well only when the overlapping of each frame is large, e.g. 23ms overlapping. Due to the memory limit, this method is not desirable to me.
  Thus, I am wondering if there is any method which is better than it?

Comment: Can you just have no overlap? Then it'd be much easier.

Comment: @AhmedFasih Yes, I can have no overlap

Comment: Depending on your application, you may be able to use MDCT (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_discrete_cosine_transform) instead of STFT.  It has windows with 50% overlap and is exactly reversible.